# Retrieve subscriber object based on List Id

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I would like to retrieve all subscribers for a list with their associated attributes.  I am using the FuelSDK.

It seems like the Subscriber Object is the correct one to use, so that I return all the attributes (not just the slimmed down properties on the SubscriberList object).

However I'm lost with trying to apply a SimpleFilterPart or some other mechanism to filter based on List.

Any pointers ?

```
        var etSubscriber = new ET_Subscriber();
        etSubscriber.AuthStub = etClient;
        //etSubscriber.SearchFilter =  new SimpleFilterPart() { Property = "List", SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals, 
        //    Value = new string[] { "3963" } };
        var subscriberReturn = etSubscriber.Get();


        var subscriberList = subscriberReturn.Results.ToList();
        subscriberList.ForEach(sub =>
        {
            var etSub = (ET_Subscriber)sub;
            etSubscriber.Attributes.ToList().ForEach(attr =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + attr.Name + " Value: " + attr.Value);
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll have to do this in two parts, since Subscriber is just for one subscriber.  After you have your subscriberList, then use the subscriber object to get additional attributes for one more subscribers.

Comment: The SOAP envelope examples are the best way to learn how to build these calls: Check on the one at the bottom of this page: https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_all_subscribers_on_a_list/

Comment: thanks. didnt think to rack up an array of subcriberid's as part of the query.
Works like a bought one!